# Unresolved external symbol when linking a precompiled module

Tags: fortran

I am trying to compile a Fortran file with an external precompiled module.
First I compile the module file with:

```
ifort /c KDTree_mod.f90
```

it generates some .mod files (kdtree2_module.mod, kdtree2_precision_module.mod, kdtree2_priority_queue_module.mod).

At the beginning of the subroutine I have:

```
subroutine film(h,tinf,ts,n,time)
use kdtree2_module
```

but when I launch the program it gives me this error:

```
user_film.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol KDTREE2_MODULE_mp_KDTREE2_CREATE referenced in function FILM
user_film.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol KDTREE2_MODULE_mp_KDTREE2_N_NEAREST referenced in function FILM
user_film.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
link failed for user_film.obj
```

Procedure:
1. compile the module with `ifort /c KDTree_mod.f90`
2. launch MSC Marc with user subroutine film.
     `run_marc -j name_input_file -u user_subroutine`
3. Error

MSC Marc is a commercial software that has the possibility to create user subroutine.

**Update:**
I tried:
1. `ifort /c KDTree_mod.f90` --> generate .obj file
   `run_marc -j name_input_file -obj name_obj.obj -u name_input_file`
   It compiles fine but suddenly error:

> forrtl: severe (170): Program Exception - stack overflow Image
>   PC                Routine            Line        Source
>
> user_film.exe   0000000141D63717  Unknown               Unknown 
>   Unknown user_film.exe   000000013FD45C96  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown user_film.exe   000000013FF1CCC7  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown user_film.exe   000000013FD9495E  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown user_film.exe   00000001405A819A  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown user_film.exe   0000000140236B11  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown user_film.exe   000000013FFE32DB  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown user_film.exe   000000013FFEE6C1  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown user_film.exe   000000013FE70FAE  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown user_film.exe   000000013FD51592  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown user_film.exe   000000013FD4105D  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown user_film.exe   00000001424CE3DC  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown user_film.exe   0000000141D638B2  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown kernel32.dll       0000000077475A4D  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown ntdll.dll          00000000775AB831  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown

2. `ifort /c KDTree_mod.f90
   ifort /c user_film.f
   run_marc -j name_input_file -obj KDtree_mod.obj user_film.obj

   read error: no such option: user_film.obj or input value: -b`
   So seems that I am not able to pass both .obj files.
3. `ifort /c KDTree_mod.f90
   ifort /c user_film.f KDTree_mod.obj
   ifort: warning #10146: no action performed for specified object file(s)`

Marc in verbose: http://pastebin.com/6rd8v5Eh

**Update 2**
I am able to compile a dll file with these commands:

```
ifort /nologo /iface:stdcall /libs:dll /threads /c KDTree_mod.f90
link /NOLOGO /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /manifest /dll /out:KDTree_mod.dll KDTree_mod.obj
mt /nologo “/outputresource:KDTree_mod.dll;#2″ /manifest KDTree_mod.dll.manifest
```

Comment: It is not enough to compile with the `.mod` file, you also have to link in the appropriate library (it will be an `.obj.` or a `.dll`). You must search the manual of your software providing the module about how to do that.

Comment: Check if the line `ifort /c KDTree_mod.f90` created also something else than the `.mod` files, perhaps an `.obj`, `.o` or `.out` or a similar file.

Comment: Yes it creates .mod and .obj files.

Comment: Describe what exactly do you do before you get the error message. You must link the `.obj` files in. Which exact command do you lunch? How do you compile and link your subroutine with the program?

Comment: MSC Marc needs to compile film somehow and incorporate the code into its execution path. We do not know how it does it, and you would need to figure out, how it does it and how it could be modified, to include linking of external objects.

Comment: Ok i will ask to support.

Comment: The point 2. in your description does not help at all. How do you launch it with your subroutine? Do you run some command? Or click some icon? How do you tell it to use your subroutine?

Comment: 2. run_marc -j name_input_file -u name_user_subroutine

Comment: Behind the scenes, `run_marc` is probably compiling and linking the user routine source code. It's likely there's an option in run_marc to show what compilation commands are performed. Perhaps some sort of `verbose` option? It would help to see those commands.

Comment: Just run the ifort command you have shown above yourself and manually add the obj file into the command. (Unfortunately you still did not describe what kind of error you got from the command you tried.)

Answer (score 0):

The most useful information I found on the internet is in this [german CAD forum](http://forum.cad.de/foren/ubb/Forum130/HTML/000539.shtml), where it says, that there is a run_marc with the following:

```
FCOMP=ifort
...
FORTRAN="$FCOMP -c -assume byterecl -safe_cray_ptr $PROFILE -save -zero -mp -WB -w90 -O1 $I8FFLAGS -I$MARC_SOURCE/common \
-I$MARC_SOURCE/bcssolver/common -I$MARC_SOURCE/mumpssolver/include $I8DEFINES -DLinux -DLINUX -DLinux_intel $FDEFINES $DDM $SOLVERFLAGS"
```

You would need to add a `-obj KDTree_mod.obj` or the like to this command line. From the descriptions there it sounds it would also be possible to link against libraries, so it might be another option to create a library and use that via a path that is more in line with the general usage of that tool.

Regarding your first update: I wouldn't have expected the `-obj` option to work for that at all. What I meant, was that you need to modify the `run_marc` script itself. According to the link above it appears to be a script with a variable containing the run script in it. It might be that this is only the case on Unix systems, and on Windows it is solved differently. Did you try to look into the `run_marc` script? I have no clue, what your first command in your update, which you say compiles, actually does what is this name_obj now all of a sudden?

In your second command, I would have expected something like:

```
run_marc -j name_input_file -u user_film -obj KDtree_mod.obj
```

Though, as outlined above, I don't think the obj gets passed on.

Regarding your second update, and your comment below:

Besides the linking you also need to have the module file available in the include path. Usually the include path of the compiler includes the current working directory, so if you can put the module file into the directory where the compiler is executed, this ought to work. Or you put it in one of the directories stated via the `-I` options in the compiling `FORTRAN` command above. Or, you modify the command and add your own include path to it.

How does this command from your pastebin look like with the `set userdll` option filled:

```
ifort  /fpp /c /DWIN32_intel  -D_IMPLICITNONE /nologo
      -DMKL -DOPENMP -DOMP_COMPAT -D_MSCMARC -DWIN64
      /I"C:\MSC.Software\Marc\2014.0.0\marc2014\common"
      /I"C:\MSC.Software\Marc\2014.0.0\marc2014\bcsgpusolver\common" 
      /I"C:\MSC.Software\Marc\2014.0.0\marc2014\mumpssolver\include" 
      /I"C:\MSC.Software\Marc\2014.0.0\marc2014\intelmpi\win64\include"
      /O2 /Qip /Qvec- /Qsafe-cray-ptr /switch:fe_old_modvar
      /W0  /Qopenmp /Qopenmp-threadprivate:compat  -DCASI -DPARDISO -DMUMPS
      -DBCSGPU -DCUDA /MD -DDDM
      /object:"C:\Users\Yellowhat\Desktop\prova\user_film.obj"
      "C:\Users\Yellowhat\Desktop\prova\user_film.f"
```

It looks like `C:\MSC.Software\Marc\2014.0.0\marc2014\common` would be a good location to put the KDTree `*.mod` files into.

Comment: Unfortunatally MSC support confirm that at the moment there is no support for FORTRAN 90.

Comment: They might not support it officially, but as they are using some installed compiler, like for example ifort, it should be possible by modifying the run_marc command above.

Comment: Following **Update 2** I am able to compile a dll file. In run_marc there is a line `set userdll=` but if I add the .dll file created to this line, at the execution same error as before **Update**